# Programatically create 'Send this user a a private message link' for user pages

Tags: privatemsg

I know that this question had been asked several times, but it seems like all existing answers only apply to ealier versions of Privatemsg module. I am running 7.x-2.x-dev and I would like to programatically render the "Send this user a private message" link. The PHP code is supposed to be the `$block['content']` of a programatically created block that will be displayed on user pages.

Somebody suggested to use

```
if ($account = menu_get_object('user') ) {
      if ($url = privatemsg_get_link(array($account))) {
        $block['content'] = l(t('Send this user a private message'), $url, array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
      }
}
```

but this is doing absolutely nothing.

I also want that the link is only displayed if the *viewed* user has enabled the "Enable private messages" option in his/her account settings and if the *viewing* user has permission to send messages. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: If "somebody suggested" something, you should link to the source or make it clear why you cannot (read in IRC, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example of how to do this, you can see the integration with the [Author Pane](https://drupal.org/project/author_pane) module in `privatemsg.author-pane.inc`:

```
  global $user;
  $account = $variables['account'];

  if ($account->uid != $user->uid) {
    $url = privatemsg_get_link($account);
    if (!empty($url)) {
      $variables['privatemsg'] = l('<span>' . t('Send PM') . '</span>', $url, array('attributes' => array('class' => array('author-pane-link'), 'title' => t('Send @name a private message', array('@name' => privatemsg_recipient_format($account, array('plain' => TRUE))))), 'html' => TRUE));
    }
  }
```

This isn't a cut-and-paste solution, but since Author Pane provides a block that allows you to PM given users, and this respects the Privatemsg permissions (the link should not be rendered if the recipient does not have appropriate permissions to receive or the sender does not have permission to send), this should be a useful reference.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to modify this code to get it to work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7, you can use [privatemsg_get_link](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_get_link/7).

- **privatemsg_get_link** - Returns a link to send message form for a specific users.

    `if ($enabled_private_messages) {//check user private message settings
      if ($account = menu_get_object('user')) {// Get user object. You can also use user_load to get user object.
        if (is_object($account) && privatemsg_user_access('write privatemsg')) {
          if ($url = privatemsg_get_link(array($account))) {
            return l(t('contact user'), $url, array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
          }
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: This answer is obviously also correct, thank you very much! However, I decided to accept the other one, since it provided me some more information how to implement the function.

Comment: Its ok.. You got the answer right, that's enough.

Comment: This can be shortened by removing all the conditionals before `if ($url = privatemsg_get_link($account)) …`. The checks are done by the [privatemsg_get_link](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_get_link/7) function.